# Connecting to RealVNC Server asks for username, but I haven't configured any

Tags: windows, realvnc

I've installed RealVNC server (Windows), authentication mode was set to *VNC password* (there is no user name to fill).

When I tried to connect to server via the viewer, it asks for password and USERNAME.
But there is no username configured on the server! I think I've enabled "Admin" check box in one of the options tabs. Could this be a reason?

What to do?

Comment: Have you tried the server's local username?

Comment: no! what do you mean server's local user name? username of the computer?

Comment: because there is no username when i install and set up the vncserver

Comment: I think I've enabled "Admin" check box i one of the options tabs of realvnc server, could this be a reason vnc viewer asks for a password?

Comment: I don't know. Let's delete our other comments, it gets too cluttered otherwise.

Comment: Have you tried ignoring the username box and just entering the password?

Answer (score 1):

If you have set the server to VNC authentication and are being prompted for a username the chances are you have configured the extended VNC authentication for the Admin or ViewOnly account.

You can either leave the username blank and just enter your vnc password, or if you don't want the extended authentication, from the Server's options dialog, select the "Configure..." button next to VNC authentication and disable the Admin or ViewOnly account.

You may have also turned on guest access, that also prompts you for a username.